# How to create kiosk mode in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, kiosk, group-policy, kiosk-mode

Is there a way to create Kiosk Mode in AD? I dont want to use web browser. We have many terminal computers that works on production. On it there is a software for weighing scales and inventarisation. I need to lock down disk C using group policy (it works on VirtualBox but doesnt work on real server) and prevent users to use any other software then the one they need.

Terminal computers are using Windows 7 Embedded.

Answer (score 1):

Windows kiosk mode need next steps:

- Create user for kiosk mode Set next registry key for this user as
  path to your application:

Windows XP/7:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\your\\application.exe>"
```

Windows 8 and later:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\your\\application.exe>"
```

Autologin for kiosk user:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon] 
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"ForceAutoLogon"="1"
"DefaultUserName"="kiosk"
"DefaultDomainName"="<place here pc hostname>"
"DefaultPassword"=""
```

[Option] If you need to disable Ctrl+Alt+Del, then use this registry key value ("") or you can place there own application:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe]
"Debugger"="\"\""
```

https://github.com/VoidVolker/kiosk#windows